# Multithreaded code won't compile using g++, but is fine with clang++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++, clang++

I am having trouble with the g++ compiler. On my work machine (running OS X 10.10.4) I was experimenting with some code using Xcode. The code did compile succesfully, and the resulting executable works as expected. Output of `clang++ --version`:

> Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on
>   LLVM 3.6.0svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0 Thread model: posix

Then I decided to compile this code on a server running Debian 8 with g++. The output of `g++ --version`:

> g++ (Debian 4.9.2-22) 4.9.2 Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc.

The code won't even compile using g++. The command I tried using: `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp`

I get the following error messages:

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:32:106: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::packaged_task'
>        std::shared_ptr > ptr(new std::packaged_task(std::bind(factorial, 6)));
>
> In file included from main.cpp:11:0:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.9/future:120:11: error: declaration of 'class std::packaged_task'
>        class packaged_task;
>              ^
>
> main.cpp:33:22: error: variable 'std::future fu1' has initializer but incomplete type
>        std::future fu1 = ptr->get_future();
>                         ^
>
> main.cpp:33:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::packaged_task'
>        std::future fu1 = ptr->get_future();
>                                  ^
>
> In file included from main.cpp:11:0:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.9/future:120:11: error: declaration of 'class std::packaged_task'
>        class packaged_task;
>              ^
>
> main.cpp: In lambda function:
>
> main.cpp:34:48: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::packaged_task'
>        std::function task1 = &ptr{ ptr->operator()(); };
>                                                   ^
>
> In file included from main.cpp:11:0:
>
> /usr/include/c++/4.9/future:120:11: error: declaration of 'class std::packaged_task'
>        class packaged_task;
>              ^
>
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:36:38: error: variable 'std::packaged_task t' has initializer but incomplete type
>        std::packaged_task t(std::bind(factorial, 5));
>                                         ^
>
> main.cpp:37:22: error: variable 'std::future fu2' has initializer but incomplete type
>        std::future fu2 = t.get_future();
>                         ^

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned long long int num)
{
    unsigned long long int N = num;
    for (unsigned long long int i = num; i > 1; --i)
    {
        num *=(--N);
    }

    return num;
}

int main()
{

    std::shared_ptr<std::packaged_task<int()> > ptr(new std::packaged_task<int()>(std::bind(factorial, 6)));
    std::future<int> fu1 = ptr->get_future();
    std::function<void()> task1 = [&ptr](){ ptr->operator()(); };

    std::packaged_task<int()> t(std::bind(factorial, 5));
    std::future<int> fu2 = t.get_future();
    std::function<void()> task2 = [&t](){ t(); };

    std::thread threads[2];

    threads[0] = std::thread(task1);
    threads[1] = std::thread(task2);

    cout << fu1.get() << endl;
    cout << fu2.get() << endl;

    threads[0].join();
    threads[1].join();

    return 0;
}
```

What could be the issue with g++?

Comment: Or better `<functional>` ;)

Comment: I included `<functional>` and got the same error message

Comment: Oops, yes `functional`. But nvm if it doesn't help anyway.

Comment: [GCC 5.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a71593a7906e3f6) will compile the code.

Comment: gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-21) also compiles it

Comment: @MagunRa Thats really weird. I have absolutely no idea why it won't compile for me.

Comment: @MagunRa tried it on a windows machine with mingw, it worked fine. something is not right on my Debian server. trying some aptitude magic in a moment

Comment: I installed g++ version 5, got the same error message again.

Comment: I could compile it successfully with g++ `4.8.2`

Comment: I guess the future header is faulty. Try to reinstall these perhaps. (It is hard to solve a problem which is related to your system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that `std::future` & `std::async` are not implemented on the armel architecture for some reason.

I can't really find out why is this (some argue on mailing lists, that they are not implemented by design, some others say this is a bug) and what is the current state of the problem.

However, I've also found a reply that stated this **may** be already resolved in the newer versions of `libstdc++`(My system is running the Testing version of debian, I do not have these versions yet, and I don't plan to get the package from unstable repos, so I'll just wait for it).

Comment: Yes, my `arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ 4.9.2` also cannot compile the code.